# ポインタの配列の受け渡し

Tags: c, array, ポインタ

c言語のポインタの配列の受け渡しの勉強をしていて、疑問に思った点があります。
以下のプログラムは、参考書の内容をそのまま貼りつけたものです。
main関数最後の方の`print(p, 3);`ですが、なぜ`print(*p, 3)`ではないのかわかりません。
int p[3]と定義したら、print(p, 3)で渡して(int x[], int no)で受け取るのは分かるのですが、類推したら、
int *p[3]と定義したら、print(*p, 3)で渡すことにはならないのでしょうか？

```
/*
    ポインタの配列の受渡し
*/

#include  <stdio.h>

/*--- ポインタの配列の値を表示 ---*/
void print(int *x[], int no)
{
    int  i;

    for (i = 0; i < no; i++)
        printf("x[%d]＝%p  *x[%d]＝%d\n", i ,x[i], i, *x[i]);
}

int main(void)
{
    int  a = 5, b = 3, c = 7;
    int  *p[3];

    p[0] = &a;  p[1] = &b;  p[2] = &c;
    printf("&a＝%p  a＝%d\n", &a, a);
    printf("&b＝%p  b＝%d\n", &b, b);
    printf("&c＝%p  c＝%d\n", &c, c);

    print(p, 3);

    return (0);
}
```

実行例

```
wn-003% ./a.out
&a＝0x7fffd19cccd4  a＝5
&b＝0x7fffd19cccd8  b＝3
&c＝0x7fffd19cccdc  c＝7
x[0]＝0x7fffd19cccd4  *x[0]＝5
x[1]＝0x7fffd19cccd8  *x[1]＝3
x[2]＝0x7fffd19cccdc  *x[2]＝7
```

ちなみにprint(*p, 3)とすると、以下のエラーが出ます。

```
junk1.c:22:8: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘print’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
  print(*p, 3);
        ^
junk1.c:4:6: note: expected ‘int **’ but argument is of type ‘int *’
 void print(int *x[], int no)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`typedef int *intp;`と型定義してみるとコードを解釈しやすくなるでしょうか？ また、式`p`は配列の先頭を表す`&p[0]`と同じ意味です。

```
typedef int *intp;

void print(intp x[], int no)
{
    int  i;

    for (i = 0; i < no; i++)
        printf("x[%d]＝%p  *x[%d]＝%d\n", i ,x[i], i, *x[i]);
}

int main(void)
{
    int  a = 5, b = 3, c = 7;
    intp p[3];

    p[0] = &a;  p[1] = &b;  p[2] = &c;
    printf("&a＝%p  a＝%d\n", &a, a);
    printf("&b＝%p  b＝%d\n", &b, b);
    printf("&c＝%p  c＝%d\n", &c, c);

    print(&p[0], 3);

    return (0);
}
```

元のソースコードを見たときに、上記コードが頭に描けるようになれば理解が進むと思います。

Answer (score 0):

```
int  *p[3];
```

と宣言していますから、pはintへのポインターの配列です。

そして、このpを引数につかう関数 print の呼び出しは次のようになっています。

```
print(p, 3);
```

そしてprint関数は、以下のように定義されています。

```
void print(int *x[], int no){
    int  i;
    for (i = 0; i < no; i++)
        printf("x[%d]＝%p  *x[%d]＝%d\n", i ,x[i], i, *x[i]);
}
```

第一引数 x はintへのポインターの配列だと宣言されていますよね。
だから、print関数を呼び出す時の第一引数の型はintへのポインターの配列じゃないとダメなんです。

Answer (score 0):

C言語ではポインタに関係して<kbd>*</kbd>を使う場面が2つありますが、それぞれで意味が異なります。

> `int  *p[3];`

で使われている<kbd>*</kbd>はポインタ型であることを意味しています。
定義した`p`は以降**特別な表現をしなければ常に`int`型のポインタの配列です。**

> `p[0] = &a;  p[1] = &b;  p[2] = &c;`

では、上記のように代入した後に例えば`*p[0] = 6;`とする場合の<kbd>*</kbd>はどういう意味なのか。
こういう場合の<kbd>*</kbd>は`p[0]`に代入されているアドレスの中身であることを意味します。
現在`p[0]`には`&a`、`int`型の変数`a`のアドレスが代入されています。従って、例示した`*p[0] = 6;`は`a = 6;`と言い換えることができます。

> ```
> void print(int *x[], int no)
> {
> (中略)
> print(p, 3);
> (後略)
> ```

結論として、関数`print`の最初の引数は`int`型のポインタの配列なので`p`で良いということになります。